# Filter left join output

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 
**jobs table** with fields

jobId, jobTitle, jobDesc

**jobQuotes Table** with fields

id, user_id, quote

jobQuotes table has the quote of users who gave quote for the job.

I need those jobs for which a specific user has NOT given any quote.

Using `LEFT JOIN` I get all the jobs irrespective of the jobQuotes table.

And `INNER JOIN` only gives all the jobs that has a relevant jobQuote.

But I need those jobs for which a specific user has NOT given any quote.

My Query is

```
SELECT * FROM dummy_jobs J LEFT JOIN jobQuotes JQ ON J.jobId=JQ.jobId WHERE MATCH (J.jobTitle, J.jobDescription) AGAINST ('php, mysql');
```

How to filter this result set so that output doesn't have specific user_id in jobQuotes?

Comment: So the only way you can get the total population of users is from jobquotes? You don't have a users table?

Comment: @P.Salmon I have users table but I am confusing it..look at my query below

Something is wrong that I am not able to figure out

SELECT * FROM dummy_jobs J LEFT JOIN jobQuotes JQ ON J.jobId=JQ.jobId LEFT JOIN users U ON JQ.userId= U.userId  WHERE MATCH (J.jobTitle, J.jobDescription) AGAINST ('php, mysql') and JQ.userId !=953;

Comment: What does "so that output doesn't have specific user_id in jobQuotes" mean? PS Please edit clarifications into posts, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS 1 re calculating EXCEPT in MySQL. 2 This is a faq. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT jobstable.jobid from jobstable inner join 
(SELECT id from jobQuotes where userid = 953 and quote IS NULL) dummy_table    
on dummy_table.id == jobstable.jobid;
```

The Answer is According to the comment you were given

"I want all jobs for which userId= 953 has not given any quote"

Comment: @rgoyal This query will give you the output correctly. I hope so

Comment: Your @ has no effect because rgoyal is not a commenter on your post. Google 'stackexchange notifications'. Put a comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

An approach might be to associate a specific user with all jobs by using a cross join and then left join to job quotes with a null test to find those not quoted for.
for example

users

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | John     |
|  2 | Jane     |
|  3 | Ali      |
|  6 | Bruce    |
|  7 | Martha   |
+----+----------+
```

Jobs

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| jobId | jobTitle | jobDesc |
+-------+----------+---------+
|     1 | a        | a       |
|     2 | b        | b       |
|     3 | c        | c       |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

Jobquotes

```
+------+---------+-------+
| id   | user_id | quote |
+------+---------+-------+
|    1 |       3 |    10 |
|    2 |       2 |    10 |
+------+---------+-------+

select t.id,t.username,t.jobid,t.jobtitle,t.jobdesc
from
(
select u.id,u.username, s.jobid,s.jobtitle,s.jobdesc
from users u
cross join (select distinct jobid , jobtitle, jobdesc from jobs) s
where u.id = 3
) t
left join jobquotes jq on jq.id = t.jobid and jq.user_id = t.id 
where jq.id is null
```

result

```
+----+----------+-------+----------+---------+
| id | username | jobid | jobtitle | jobdesc |
+----+----------+-------+----------+---------+
|  3 | Ali      |     2 | b        | b       |
|  3 | Ali      |     3 | c        | c       |
+----+----------+-------+----------+---------+
```